# Images not visible while deploying on github

Tags: github-pages

I am facing a problem with the site published using GitHub. The images are not getting displayed when I publish the site. However, it is displayed on my local computer.

The images are present in the img folder.

I am not able to get where is the problem occurring and how to resolve it.

github repo link: https://github.com/Scientist69/Gym-Webpage

GitHub deployment link: https://scientist69.github.io/Gym-Webpage/

Comment: if you look at browser console your see they are 404, if you look at the path to the image your missing the `Gym-Webpage` part, due to using absolute path rather then relative

Answer (score 0):

try removing the first slash(/) in image links in index.html.

```
 <img src="/img/bg.webp" alt="" />
```

To

```
 <img src="img/bg.webp" alt="" />
```